# Асинхронная загрузка данных SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

Есть класс `Repository`:

```
public class Repository
{
    private static readonly Model db = new Model();

    public static async Task LoadDB() => await db.Clients.LoadAsync();
}
```

Код загрузки данных из БД:

```
private async void LoadDataGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Repository.LoadDB();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { 
        ShowInfo(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

Я надеялся, что интерфейс не будет подвисать на момент загрузки БД, но он всё равно зависает.
В чем может быть проблема?

У меня `.NET Core 3.1` + `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`

Gif проблемы:

[image]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127002/discussion-on-question-by-----sqlite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Async limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/async)

> SQLite doesn't support asynchronous I/O. Async ADO.NET methods will execute synchronously in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Avoid calling them.

---

Ограничения асинхронного режима

> SQLite не поддерживает асинхронный ввод-вывод. Асинхронные методы ADO.NET будут выполняться синхронно в Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Старайтесь не вызывать их.

---

В этом случае поможет запуск отдельной задачи.
В комментариях @aepot предложил следующее решение:

```
public static Task LoadDB() => Task.Run(async () => await db.Clients.LoadAsync());
```

Но так как с sqlite асинхронные методы всё равно работают синхронно, то ещё лучше избавиться от них:

```
public static Task LoadDB() => Task.Run(() => db.Clients.Load());
```